# PySpark - Dataframe Manipulations

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark and trying out various things to understand Spark. Currently, I have a CSV that I am trying to parse and manipulate it to my required format. I am not understanding how to do pivot and get the output or by any other means as well. My CSV looks like this:

```
AHeader AValue, BHeader BValue, CHeader CValue
```

Now the CSV output I am trying to build is something like this:

```
AHeader, AValue
BHeader, BValue
CHeader, CValue
```

This is my current code:

```
datafile_csv = "test.csv"

def process_csv(abspath, sparkcontext):
    sqlContext = SQLContext (sparkcontext)
    df = sqlContext.read.load (os.path.join (abspath, datafile_csv),
                               format='com.databricks.spark.csv',
                               inferSchema='true')

    df.registerTempTable("currency")
    print "Dataframe:"
    display(df)
    // Don't know what to do here ????
    reshaped_df = df.groupby('_c0')
    display(reshaped_df)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    abspath = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    conf = (SparkConf ()
            . setMaster("local[20]")
            . setAppName("Currency Parser")
            . set("spark.executor.memory", "2g"))
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
    process_csv (abspath, sc)
```

I am not sure how I can convert this dataframe to the expected output. Do I need to transpose all the columns to rows and then do SparkSQL on them? What is the correct solution for this?

Comment: You'll need to use a custom line separator to parse this, which I don't think databricks will support. Try [pandas read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), defining your `lineterminator` as the comma, and space as the column separator.

Comment: @Andrew can you help me on how this can be done with Pandas? Not sure as I am new to Spark ecosystem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking two questions here. First question is the ETL question of loading your CSV properly, which might be better done in `pandas` (due to your narrowly specific data structure) such as:

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from io import StringIO

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
TESTDATA = StringIO("""AHeader AValue, BHeader BValue, CHeader CValue""")

pandas_df = pd.read_csv(TESTDATA,  # replace with path to your csv
                        delim_whitespace=True,
                        lineterminator=",",
                        header=None,
                        names=['col1', 'col2'])
spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(pandas_df)
spark_df.show()

+-------+------+
|   col1|  col2|
+-------+------+
|AHeader|AValue|
|BHeader|BValue|
|CHeader|CValue|
+-------+------+
```

Your second question is regarding a pivot in `spark`. While the `pandas.read_csv()` puts it into the shape you asked for, if you need further reshaping, have a look here: http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.3/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=pivot#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.pivot